# Определить количество строк в которых сумма элементов меньше 10

Tags: visual-basic

Помогите пожалуйста, укажите на ошибки, пожалуйста. Условие: задано матрицу 10х10 в DataGridView. Надо определить количество строк в которых сумма элементов меньше 10.
Вот код:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim i, j, s, k As Integer
        k = 0
        For j = 0 To 9
            s = 0
            For i = 0 To 9
                s = Val(A(0, i).Value) + Val(A(1, i).Value) + Val(A(2, i).Value) + Val(A(3, i).Value) + Val(A(4, i).Value) + Val(A(5, i).Value) + Val(A(6, i).Value) + Val(A(7, i).Value) + Val(A(8, i).Value) + Val(A(9, i).Value)
                If s < 10 Then
                    k = k + 1
                End If
            Next i
        Next j
        TextBox1.Text = k
```

Comment: @Pawa_S чем-то неуловимо напоминает @Mary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, j, s, k As Integer
    k = 0
    For j = 0 To 9
        s = 0
        For i = 0 To 9
            s += Val(A(j, i).Value)
        Next i
        If s < 10 Then
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
    TextBox1.Text = k
```

Comment: можно еще спросить?
  {s += Val(A(j, i).Value)} что значит +=?

Comment: += - это оператор добавления к текущему значению переменной, т.е. если a = 5, то после a += 6 переменная а станет равна 11